# Editing html file in uiwebview

Tags: ipad, ios4, ios5, xcode4.2

I am trying to edit a html file in uiwebview using contenteditability feature of ios 5. After editing, I just want to reload the edited content in same uiwebview without changing the format and all. How can I do that???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[webView loadHTMLString:[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"]; baseURL:nil];
```